# can a service connection to .net mvc wsdl be made with an reac-native project

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, react-native, wsdl

I have an .net MVC project. I have a wsdl service in my project. The methods in wsdl can be used with react-native?

How can I do if I have this possibility?

I tried it with soap but I was not successful.

Can you give me a sample or suggestion?